# Why CVS reader app fail to open my file

Tags: android, csv

In my application I write data to a csv file and then I want to let the user review it using some csv reader application that the device may have.
The code to open the reader application is as follows:

```
String dataType = "text/csv";
if(!hasCSVReader(dataType)) {
    Log.i(TAG, "text/csv reader aplication was not found");
    dataType = "text/*";
}
i.setDataAndType(uri, dataType);
try {
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "OMW: Open history file..."));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "No CSV or text reader application installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

and hasCSVReader(..) is as follows:

```
//check if dataType reader is installed 
private boolean hasCSVReader(String dataType) {
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setType(dataType);
    return (pm.queryIntentActivities(i, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY).size() > 0);
}
```

In my LG device `hasCSVReader(..)` returns false so the data type is `"text/*"` and one of the listed applications to choose from is "Polaris Viewer 4" which manage to open the csv file.

In a Samsung 3 device `hasCSVReader(..)` returns true, the data type is `"text/csv"`, the listed applications are "Polaris Viewer 4.1" and "OfficeSuite", but both fail to open the file.
When I set data type to `"text/*"` I get a lot more applications but none of which manage to open the file.

Note that navigating to the file using android file explorer (or whatever its name) and opening it, lists again the Polaris Viewer 4.1 and OfficeSuite, but now both manage to open the file with no problems.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If there is no cure, as a workaround I would like to open the File Manager with the specified folder. How can I do that?